# Client-side translation does not work in CKAN

Tags: internationalization, ckan

I am having issues with translating client-side text in CKAN. My site is in french, so here is the problem:
- if I click on the green button "S'abonner" from the left, it should change the button to a red one and show the text "Se désabonner", but instead, it shows me "Unfollow", like in the photos:
[image]

[image]

And if I click it again it shows me "Follow" (instead of "S'abonner"). So this is a problem on the client side. Normally, when you generate text on the server side you write in the templates _('msgid present in pofile'), but, on the client side, it uses the result from the AJAX call to "/api/i18n/{language}".

I did some digging and it seems that the client-side translation uses the result from the AJAX call to "/api/i18n/fr", but all I get is a json object:

```
{
"": {
"domain": "ckan",
"lang": "fr",
"plural-forms": "nplurals=2; plural=(n > 1)"
}
}
```

But, if I look at the ckan demo website, (`http://demo.ckan.org/api/i18n/fr`), I get a long JSON file, that contains all the translations.
 I managed to discover from where this Ajax call is done, apparently it comes from : "src/ckan/ckan/public/base/javascript/client.js", at the function:

```
getLocaleData: function (locale, success, error) {
  var url = this.url('/api/i18n/' + (locale || ''));
  return jQuery.getJSON(url).then(success, error);
}

 If I replace 
var url = this.url('/api/i18n/' + (locale || ''));
```

with

```
var url = this.url('http://demo.ckan.org/api/i18n/fr')
```

the problem is solved, because I get the translations in the json object.
     My question is how I can get the right data to be generated, is there a parameter to put in production.ini? Unfortunately, the documentation in CKAN is really poor so I have no leads on this. Does anybody have a clue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you might be running an unreleased branch of CKAN (eg master), so the Javascript translations have not been built.

This is done with the following command:

```
paster front-end-build -c config_file.ini
```

Just run this command and the translations should come up fine.

On the main repository this is only done just before releases to avoid complicating the git history.

Check for instance this site running the latest master branch, but on which the front end is built every night:

http://master.ckan.org/fr/dataset/world-countries

Comment: I applied your command and it does not seem to be recognised by paster. Here is the output: Command 'front-end-build' not known (you may need to run setup.py egg_info)

Comment: are you running it from the ckan folder ({virtualenv}/src/ckan) ?